FFmpeg CPU Usage
Im using FFmpeg.AutoGen api to decode video stream. The problem is when i have one process, it consumes about 0.5% of cpu,
screenshot from task manager:

but when im trying to open more such processes (about 20) each of them takes up to 3% and its critical for me.
another screenshot from task manager:

Both reading packets and decoding happens in different threads.
Reading func
private static unsafe void Read(VideoStreamReader reader)
{
    while (true)
    {
        reader.TryReadNextPacket();
    }
}

 public void TryReadNextPacket()
 {
     ffmpeg.av_read_frame(_pFormatContext, _pPacket);

     if (_pPacket->stream_index == _streamIndex)
         Program.packets.Enqueue(*_pPacket);
     else
         ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(_pPacket);
 }

Decoding func
 private static unsafe void Decode(VideoStreamDecoder decoder)
 {
     while (true)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"{packets.Count} BEFORE");
         if (packets.Count > 0)
         {
             packets.TryDequeue(out var packet);
             Console.WriteLine($"{packets.Count} AFTER");
             decoder.TryReadNextFrame(out var frame, packet);

             _frame = frame;
         }
         else
         {
             Thread.Sleep(40);
         }
     }
 }

public void TryReadNextFrame(out AVFrame frame, AVPacket packet)
{
    ffmpeg.avcodec_send_packet(_pCodecContext, &packet);
    ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(&packet);
    ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame(_pCodecContext, _pFrame);
    ffmpeg.av_hwframe_transfer_data(_receivedFrame, _pFrame, 0);
    frame = *_receivedFrame;
}

I tried disabling rendering(im using vulkan for it), but CPU still grows with processes, so its not the problem.
Also tried to disable decoding, leaving only rendering running and CPU usage was stable, so its definitely not the problem.

I think it is a resource contention issue. Have you tried using a number of processes that is lower than the number of available CPU cores? Also reading 20 files from disc can cause some delay in performance. I suggest to start with a lower number of processes and grow progressively to better understand if and when the resource contention arise.

First, im reading from rtsp, not from file, and second, it keeps growing for every process i start, e.g. for 2 processes its from 0.3 to 0.8%, got 6 processes its from 0.8 to 1.2 and so on. If i switch from main camera channel to sub, which has lower resouliton it becomes much better(less than 0.1% for 1-2 processes), but it still grows(about 0.6 for 20). But i dont want it to be low, im okay with it being up to 2% for every process, i just want it to be stable

Context-switching between multiple processes will cause more cache misses, meaning the same amount of work takes more CPU cycles.  Perhaps if you can get the scheduler to context-switch less frequently, so each one can get a larger batch of work done for the same context-switch overhead.  Also, each FFMpeg instance might be starting multiple decode threads, making the problem worse.

dont understand
